Kernel code PMTU update with PBR rules on L4 ports
I am studying kernel routing code and notably PMTU management.
When sending an UDP packet (with DF flag set) the kernel stack is using a flowi4 with UDP sport and dport set, for fib_lookup [1]. Consequently in case of the presence of ip rule configurations based on L4 ports, we could have a different next-hop depending on the L4 ports of the routed packets.
In the case I receive an ICMP packet of type UNREACH FRAG_NEEDED, we go to udp err_handler [2], and this function will do a route lookup to retrieve the dst_entry of the next-hop that has been used to output the original packet. However this lookup is based on a flowi4 without sport and dport [3], so the returned dst_entry could not be the one that is used when sending UDP packets, and so the pmtu update could not apply.
Am I right and there is a bug here, or do I miss something ?
[1] https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12/source/net/ipv4/udp.c#L1233
[2] https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12/source/net/ipv4/udp.c#L771
[3] https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12/source/net/ipv4/route.c#L1110

The payload of the ICMP error message will contain IP and 64 bits of the original datagram, As RFC 792, INTERNET CONTROL MESSAGE PROTOCOL explains:

The internet header plus the first 64 bits of the original datagram's
data. This data is used by the host to match the message to the
appropriate process. If a higher level protocol uses port numbers,
they are assumed to be in the first 64 data bits of the original
datagram's data.

You need to dig a little deeper into the ICMP error datagram to see the original source and destination port numbers.

Not sure to understand your answer, sorry. I do not ask about how to retrieve udp ports from icmp packets, that is already done into udp err_handler (__udp4_lib_err()). But why these ports are not used during the route lookup, to get the orginal dst_entry in order to update the pmtu (ipv4_sk_update_pmtu()).

Routing happens at layer-3 (IP), not layer-4 (transport: UDP, TCP, SCTP, DCCP, etc.). IP knows nothing about the transport layer protocol. Some transport protocols use port numbers and some do not.

Routing does supports L4 ports for policy base routing, the port information is used to determine which routing table to use, you can check "ip rule".

Routing is by the layer-3 address (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.). Routing forwards layer-3 packets between different networks (internet).  IP (Internet Protocol) knows nothing about the layer-4 protocol. Not all layer-4 protocols even use port numbers, but IP can carry any of them without knowing anything about them; they are just the payload of the layer-3 packet. Routing tables have the layer-3 destination networks in them, but nothing about layer-4. ICMP is an integral part of IP, and its error contains the first 64-bits of the data so it may have the transport addresses.

In any case, the ICMP error message payload will contain the original IP header and the UDP port numbers, so it is exactly everything you need to tell the process that the packets sent is too large for the path.
